Where should we place React-Hook-Form Controller when integrating with MUI components?
I'm very confused about where to place React-Hook-Form Controller when integrating with MUI CheckBox, Select or RadioGroup. Take following two code snippets as examples.
<Grid xs={12}>
    <Controller
        name="gender"
        control={control}
        rules={{required: "Gender is required."}}
        render={({field}) => (
            <FormControl {...field} error={!!errors.gender}>
                <FormLabel error={false}>Gender</FormLabel>
                <RadioGroup row>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Radio/>}
                        label="Male"
                        value="male"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Radio/>}
                        label="Female"
                        value="female"
                    />
                </RadioGroup>
                <FormHelperText>{errors.gender ? errors.gender?.message : " "}</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
        )}
    />
</Grid>

<Grid xs={12}>
    <FormControl error={!!errors.gender}>
        <FormLabel error={false}>Gender</FormLabel>
        <Controller
            name="gender"
            control={control}
            rules={{required: "Gender is required."}}
            render={({field}) => (
                <RadioGroup row {...field}>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Radio/>}
                        label="Male"
                        value="male"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Radio/>}
                        label="Female"
                        value="female"
                    />
                </RadioGroup>
            )}
        />
        <FormHelperText>{errors.gender ? errors.gender?.message : " "}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
</Grid>

Both code snippets work fine and I don't know where should I place the Controller. I've studied the React-Hook-Form documentation but it doesn't mention it. There are only examples demonstrating the callback function inside the render props of Controller returns Input or Select simply. However, frequently MUI CheckBox, Select or RadioGroup are wrapped by FormControl. Could someone please provide suggestions?

Simply, You only need to put FotmControlLabel or RadioGroup or any necessarry input components in render props, for example:
<section>
    <label>Radio Group</label>
    <Controller
      render={({ field }) => (
        <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" {...field}>
          <FormControlLabel
            value="female"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Female"
          />
          <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
        </RadioGroup>
      )}
      name="RadioGroup"
      control={control}
    />
</section>

In the Github repository of the React-Hook-Form package, there is an "examples" directory consisting of many examples of the different input fields. You can find MUI components input fields integrated with React-Hook-Form there.
Examples
MUI integrated input components examples (Radio group, Switch, Checkbox, Select, etc)

If an error message is required for the RadioGroup, then FormHelperText will be used, and FormControl will also be used to wrap the RadioGroup and FormHelperText. In this case, should I place the Controller outside render props or inside render props? @CaRL

You don't need to place the Controller inside the render prop; render is a prop for the RHF Controller. This prop gives you three arguments: 1.field 2.fieldState 3.formState. You can check what the field state is (for example the error state) and display a proper error message.
https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller/controller
